# Dlls in a separate process?

Tags: .net, com

I understand the difference between a .lib and a .dll.

I have an executeable: a.exe, which references b.dll. When I launch a.exe, then a new windows process created for a.exe, but there is no windows process for b.dll. Is b.dll represented as a windows process?

Comment: No, a DLL is loaded into a process started by an EXE.

Answer (score 5):

The DLL is loaded into the address space of the executable, it is not a separate process.  There are two ways a DLL is loaded.  Either by the PE loader in Windows or by using [LoadLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [GetProcAddress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/ms683212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

If the DLL is referenced when the exe is compiled and linked the [Import Address Table](http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Understanding_imports.html) is written.  This allows the PE loader to find the required DLLs and reference the required functions as part of starting a process.  DLLs have a corresponding export address table that allows the loader to find the required functions.

[CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php) is a useful tool for understanding the PE format.  In particular the import and export tables are visible.